# Using more than 26 indices in tf.einsum?

Tags: python, tensorflow, numpy-einsum

Is it possible to use more than 26 lower case letters as indices in `tf.einsum`?

Numpy allows for also using upper case letters i.e. `np.einsum('zA,AB->zB',M1,M2)` whereas `tf.einsum` returns an error.

This would be very useful for contracting tensor networks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible.

TensorFlow validates the equation passed to `einsum` [using the following regular expression](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0ffefe178f71ddb595471ddfc43edb8d702155ca/tensorflow/python/ops/special_math_ops.py#L164-L168):

```
match = re.match('([a-z,]+)(->[a-z]*)?', equation)
if not match:
  raise ValueError(
      'Indices have incorrect format: %s' % equation
  )
```

Any character not in the class `[a-z]` will cause the function to raise an error. Since TensorFlow's `einsum` function does not support ellipses `...` and all axes must be explicitly labelled, this entails that only tensors with 26 dimensions or fewer can be operated upon.